# Is it legal to use the sounds of Google Translator to use them on my own website?

Tags: copyright

I would like to know if it is legal to use the sounds of Google Translator to use them on my own website?

For example, when you go to:
https://translate.google.com/#en/es/computer

And you click on the speaker icon, you get back a sound for the word: "computer".

Is any problem with Google copyrights?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://translate.google.com has a link in the footer to [Privacy & Terms](http://www.google.com/url?rs=rssf&q=http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/), which leads to Google's general [Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/), which says:

> Using our Services does not give you ownership of any intellectual property rights in our Services or the content you access. You may not use content from our Services unless you obtain permission from its owner or are otherwise permitted by law.

I would look into the paid services provided by the [Google Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) instead, and see if those can serve your purposes.

Comment: what about if I use that API to get the sounds (paying for the API service), then I save that sound into my website for future use but paying only the first time?, maybe is an analog case that if I use the API to translate a piece of text, then I keep that translated text and keep using it as a fixed text on some section of my website.

Comment: You'd have to check the ToS of the API :) My guess would be that's an intended use-case since you're paying for it, but I'm not sure. A quick search didn't find any clarification about that on the Cloud site, but I probably missed something.

Comment: The synthesized output itself is not protected by copyright (auto-conversions lack creativity), but their programs are. So this is a case where running any program infringes copyright, hence the license, and the license could effectively say "you can't even use stuff resulting from the program that *isn't* protected by copyright.